# Função criada não reconhecida no OnClick aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspx

Olá, possuo uma página aspx no asp net, onde possui um botão que irei utilizar para limpar todos os campos do meu formulário.

utilizando um link button com as seguintes configurações

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btnLimpar" OnClick="LimparCampos" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info mr-2">Limpar</asp:LinkButton>
```

No arquivo aspx.cs possuo a função declarada

```
public void LimparCampos()
{
   numeroProtocolo.Text = "";
   numeroLote.Text = "";
   numeroProcesso.Text = "";
   remetente.Text = "";
   dataDe.Value = null;
   dataAte.Value = null;
}
```

porém mesmo com os 2 lados feitos eu recebo a mensagem

```
Parameters does not match with the method signature
```

Alguem faz alguma ideia do possível problema?

No inicio do meu aspx está sendo importado

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="ConsultarProtocolo.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="true" Inherits="HBSisConselho.pgsProcesso.ConsultarProtocolo" %>
```

Comment: Acredito que é mais fácil fazer essa limpeza usando o próprio `HTML` em vez de manda um comando ao servidor. Algo do tipo: `<input type="reset" value="Limpar campos" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tente adicionar isso nos parametros do seu métodos

```
public void SeuMetodo(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
   //limpeza dos dados e bla bla bla
}
```

caso somente isso não funcione, adicione a mão o evento ao seu componente asp, no page_load, abaixo da validação

```
if (!Page.isPostBack) { 
   lnkSeuBotao.Click += new EventHandler(SeuMetodo); 
//aqui direcionados ao componente o evento que a gente quer tratar e o que ele deve fazer ao ser chamado, no caso, chamar o 'SeuMetodo'
}
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida, entre em contato :D